# Find and fill input field using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, fill, autofill, blank-line

I want to create a bot to fill the blank on site. But unfortunately it does not work; I mean does not see or I don't know what is its problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from datetime import datetime


def login_at_specific_time(username, password, target_time):
    driver_path = "path_to_driver"
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = driver_path
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    website_url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher" 
    driver.get(website_url)

    while True:
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

        if current_time >= target_time:
           
            username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "usernameUserInput")
            username_field.send_keys(username)

            password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
            password_field.send_keys(password)

            break

        time.sleep(10)

    driver.quit()

login_at_specific_time(username="aabbcc", password="12345678a", target_time="21.45")
```

Comment: The username input on Instagram does not have an ID: `<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" class="_aa4b _add6 _ac4d _ap35" dir="" type="text" value="" name="username">` See: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/

Answer (score 0):

Here's sending the username to the username input.

It lets the page load first, then looks for the input element ([Instagram's](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher) happens to include HTML attribute `name=username`).

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
website_url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher"
driver.get(website_url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))

username_field.send_keys("some_username_or_variable")

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Ideally, the page would load the username and password fields at the same time, so you can add that in without an issue. Wrap this in your time functionality properly.

---

Additionally, I'd refactor your loop to be some format of:

```
while datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") < target_time: 
    pass

username_field = driver.find_element(...
```